# GIMP 2.10 - Bump Map not working

Tags: gimp, text

I'm trying to create a piece of beveled text.  Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create the text in a layer.
2. Apply the bump map filter with the text layer selected, using the text layer as the AUX channel.
3. Nothing happens. :(

So...what am I doing wrong?

I tried adding a gaussian blur effect before applying the bump map, but that didn't seem to help.  It's especially strange since I seemed to be able to make it work correctly a little while ago.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your Layers list (with properly named layers)?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. The bump map filter [seems to work](https://imgur.com/a/AnqeF1L) using a blurred text layer as the input.

Comment: Yeah I should've figured it wouldn't be replicate-able...

Comment: @DanielWoodfield OK. So, just one thing to note: in my example, the background of each layer is solid white with black text. There's no transparency. Perhaps that's the issue? I don't think the bumpmap works with transparency.

Answer (score 1):

The bump can affect to a place where's nothing to bump. I used the grey text as the map imput. The text layer is small. Without any Offset it affects the top left corner of my full image size background layer

[image]

The colored area of the brown layer is mostly deleted to transparent. The Bump map seems to make nothing:

[image]

But after making the text layer to image sized (it's in the Layer menu) the Bump map works, The text layer is moved to bottom to show the effect. The bump is just at the same place as the text:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, maybe it's depending on the type of layer your text is on, solid/transparent, it needs something solid to "bump away" from. Otherwise, double clicking the image at question mark in Aux Input and changes should apply.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

[image]

But remember that bump mapping is all about adding shadows, so if your text layer is black (or very dark) there won't be much to see, and if your initial layer is grey this is pretty close to the "no level change" values (50% gray) so the effect is hardly visible and you have to increase the "depth".